# how to send ajax request in jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

here is the function

```
  jQuery(function($){

    $('#tabs').tabs({

      beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui.ajaxSettings);

        if(ui.ajaxSettings.url == 'productstab/ajax/index'){
          ui.ajaxSettings.type = 'post';
        }
        ui.ajaxSettings.dataFilter = function(data, type){

        var html = data,
                   obj;
        try {
            obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            html = obj.test_element;
        } catch (e) {}
            return html;
        }
      },

    })

  });
```

i've tried

```
ui.ajaxSettings.username = "foo";
ui.ajaxSettings.password = "bar";
```

or

```
  ajaxOptions: {
      username: "foo",
      password: "bar"
  },
```

but i can't still send request. how can i do that?

-------update-------

```
      ui.ajaxSettings.url += "?username=tester";
      ui.ajaxSettings.type = 'get';
```

rewrite to this get use get to send request
but i want to use post, any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use this approach? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix

```
      ui.ajaxSettings.type = 'POST'; 
      ui.ajaxSettings.hasContent = true;
      ui.jqXHR.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", ui.ajaxSettings.contentType );
      ui.ajaxSettings.data = jQuery.param( { username: 'tester'},  ui.ajaxSettings.traditional );
```